# Why I can't connect my telegram bot to Mongodb Atlas using Python?

Tags: python, heroku, pymongo, python-telegram-bot

This is my code

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

def get_db(update, context):
    cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://testing:12345678@cluster0.gs9k5.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    result = list(cluster.get_database('DBNAME')['COLLECTIONNAME'].find({}))
    update.message.reply_text(str(result))

def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("getdb", get_db))

    updater.start_webhook(listen="#.#.#.#",
                          port=int(PORT),
                          url_path=TOKEN)
    updater.bot.setWebhook('https://MYHEROKUAPP.herokuapp.com/' + TOKEN)

    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Everytime I type `/getdb`, the bot doesn't give me any response. When I tried several experiments, Seems there's some Error on cluster variable. I used try except syntax, but the bot didn't show anything, even from the except and I couldn't found the Error name as well. And I'm using heroku server for the telegram bot. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to default db (which is the one defined in the connection string) and query the collections like this

```
client = MongoClient('connect-string')
db = client.get_default_database()
# 'collection_name' is the name of the Mongo collection
list = db.collection_name.find()
```

Comment: I appreciate your Answer but There are no differences between your code and my code (especially the cluster variable and the client variable are the same)

Comment: Code is very similar, the difference is using the `get_default_database` and using the dict key instead of `get()` which improves readability and less error-prone (no need to hardcode the db name). Do you get some info in the stacktrace? Did you try `client .server_info`?

Comment: It is also a good practice avoiding connection string and credentials in your questions

Comment: I have tried your code,  but still no response from it.

Comment: No errors? just no response? Did you whitelist the IP address from where you connect from? I have allowed all (`0.0.0.0/0 `)

Comment: No errors and no response, I pushed the bot into heroku server, maybe it can't reach the mongodb? Because the heroku server located in US, and the mongodb located in Asia, Singapore.

Comment: It should be fine. Can you connect from your local env?

Comment: Yes, I can connect from local env. How about from heroku server?

Comment: Heroku doesnt stop outgoing connections (I do connect to Atlas without problems). In Atlas security I whitelisted all IPs

Comment: I changed into heroku server, but there is not still no response from function that connects to mongodb. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add `0.0.0.0/0 ` whitelist in Atlas?

Comment: Yes, i have. But still there's no response from the bot.

Comment: Ok , I found my error, I forgot to add ```dnspython``` in ```requirements.txt```. I should watch carefully in the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still have this issue, but the code seems to be okay so far.
Try logging the app info to the terminal to get a better idea of what the error is.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                        level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

1. It may be that your MongoDB Atlas is not allowing connection from the server you are running your code from. You can check your cluster to see if it allows access to the DB from your server. You can add the IP address of your server to the cluster to allow it succesfully access the data.
2. If the collection you're trying to display all items from is large, Telegram will throw an error because the ensuing message will be too long. Ensure that you're running your test with only a few items in your test database.
3. You should be ale to check your heroku logs or in your terminal to see what other errors might be happening

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have solved the issue which i forgot to install dnspython